# Ubuntu Server 22.04 SSH ChrootDirectory not behaving as expected when accessing via SFTP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

Generally after successfully logging in via `sftp` and executing a `put` command I would expect my file to transfer to the logged in user's `$HOME` directory.  This works out of the box, but I would like to restrict the `sftp` user to their `$HOME` directory (so they can't `cd` up any more levels for example).

This is where I am using `ChrootDirectory` - per the documentation (https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

> ChrootDirectory: Specifies a path to chroot(2) to after authentication. This path, and all its components, must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group

I believe I have setup the folders / permissions correctly.  The next sentence of the documentation I believe is not working or behaving as expected.

> After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

After modifying `sshd_config` to use `ChrootDirectory` and successfully accessing the server via `sftp` the users working directory is NOT set to the users $HOME directory, it is actually set to one level above.  (e.g. `/home` instead of `/home/userTest`)
The obvious fix for the user is to cd into the correct directory one level below but if you are using some automated system that simply FTPs data to the current working directory this can be very problematic.

I will first show the general case then modify it to show how the default working directory behavior changes once `ChrootDirectory` is introduced to `sshd_config`

This works as expected:

1. Create the user (use `-m` to create this users home directory): `sudo useradd -m userTest`
2. Give the user a password: `sudo passwd userTest`
3. Note `userTest` $HOME directory:  `cat /etc/passwd` -> `userTest:x:1002:1004::/home/userTest:/bin/sh`
4. sftp to your server for the user you just created: `sftp userTest@<your-server>`
5. Note the working directory after successfully logging in: `pwd` -> `Remote working directory: /home/userTest`

The above example is working exactly as expected, the only issue is `userTest` is not locked into the working directory and can `cd ..` to the reset of the file system.

Several guides have all had the same basic solution to this problem (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

Adding on to the previous steps

1. Add an sftp group (this will be used as a key for our `Match` block in `sshd_config`): `sudo addgroup sftp`
2. Add `userTest` user to the group: `sudo usermod -a -G sftp userTest`
3. Edit `sshd_config`: `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
4. Add the following lines to the end of the file

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

(This basically means any user belonging to the `sftp` group will be subjected to the `ChrootDirectory` and `ForceCommand` rules)

Save file and restart ssh:  `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

Verify the directory specified by `ChrootDirectory` satisfies the requirements from the documentation above:  `ls -ltr` -> `drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Jun 10 09:02 home` (this passes I believe)

Compare results from out of the box setup vs. with our new config
sftp using `userTest` again: `sftp userTest@<your-server>`

Note the current working directory: `pwd` -> `Remote working directory: /`

This isn't a dead giveaway that something is wrong, we expect the working directory to change... however lets quickly check the contents of the current working directory:

`ls -ltr` -> `drwxr-x---    3 1002     1004         4096 Jun 10 09:10 userTest`(!!!)

Per the documentation:

> After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory.

`ls -ltr` shows us that the working directory is NOT in the `userTest` home directory, it is actually one level ABOVE.

Is there a way to configure `ChrootDirectory` or some other way to make this work as expected?

NOTE:  Removing `ForceCommand` from sshd_config actually causes this other issue that was closed as ERRATA 11 years ago?
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=681202

Comment: Do you have another /etc/passwd file inside the chroot environment? Check its value for home directory.

Comment: No, this is the only one:  


-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1905 Jun 10 09:02 /etc/passwd